# Outer div background visible arround inner div in Chrome

Tags: html, css

This happens in the Layout, which is now layout both in normal view and in device-mode (F12) when the scale or width of the view changes. I created a minimalistic test case in which this also manifests itself in device-mode. Help me get rid of these stripes please.

## Images:

General markup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/09OGl.jpg

Test case(Chrome F12 device mode): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAj4C.png

```
  

    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Document</title>
            <style>
                header {background-color:green}
                section {background-color: blue}
                footer {background-color: aquamarine}
                .inner-div {
                    background-color:white;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>Header</header>
            <section>
                Section
                <div class="inner-div">Inner</div>
            </section>
            <footer>Footer</footer>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Snippet:

```css
header {background-color:green}
section {background-color: blue}
footer {background-color: aquamarine}
.inner-div {
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<section>
    Section
    <div class="inner-div">Inner</div>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Browsers have default css, 1 of your elements probably has some `padding` or `margin` that has been added by the browser. Try adding something like `*{margin: 0; padding:0;};` and see if this changes anything

Comment: Jeremy, as i see is not padding and margin problem. width of stripes less than 1 px and appearing disapperaring randomly during changing of with https://imgur.com/YUk194W

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately something that is device/browser-specific - for example, I do not get bleeding with your example in Chromium no matter the configuration:
[image]

A common solution would be much akin to how this is approached with seams on shape contact in SVG - either add a light effect to mask the contact area (via `outline` or `box-shadow`), or make shapes lightly overlap (`margin-top: -1px` would be enough for your original case).

Comment: YellowAfterlife, plese change IPhone profile to Responsive(not limited by min width) and you maybe can see that effect https://imgur.com/eMLS1d7.

Comment: Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmZ64.png) with identical settings and yet no bleeding.

Comment: But anyway this code ```*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Removes padding behaviour on widths */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}``` from guy with Indian name very reduce problem(him removed his message). But not completed(device mode) and scaling. But at now it is solution for normal view vithout stipes.