# Child div left border overlaps parent div bottom border in Chrome with display scaling at 125%

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

I currently have the following markup an CSS:

```css
.test1 {
  border: solid 2px #003C88;
  height: 100px;
}

.test2 {
  height: 100%;
  border-left: solid 8px #FBCE07;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

in Chrome + Windows 10 with monitor scaling set to 125% the left border of the child div overlaps the bottom border by 1px. If I increase the scaling above 100% the issue disappears. In Firefox and Chrome + Windows Server 2008 the borders are displayed correctly regardless of scaling.

Comment: There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57711062/5578773) yesterday - supposedly Chrome is (currently?) just bad with display scaling on Windows so workarounds are required

Comment: Thanks very much @YellowAfterlife. I've tested with scaling set to 250% and the issue disappears, so I'll park this as out of my control for now. However I'll leave the question for posterity, until the stackoverflow gods deem it unnecessary.